# How does F# inline work?

Tags: c#, f#, inline

With F# it is my understanding that you can use the inline keyword to perform type specialization at the call site. That is::

```
val inline (+) : ^a -> ^b -> ^c
      when (^a or ^b) : (static member (+) : ^a * ^b -> ^c)
```

Constrains that `^a` or `^b` must have a static member like `op_Addition`, or one of the built in primitives, that can be used to fill in the gap.

So if you have a method that has a + and you pass in an int and a short as parameters it unwraps + to an instruction to use the built in primitive for int, and if you pass in a float and a byte it uses the float primitive addition opcode.

How exactly is this done at compile time? How can you have a method in the CLR that switches what opcode or method it uses based on the type?

Is this behavior possible with Reflection.Emit? 
I understand that the inlining is performed at the call-site, does that mean that the code does not work with C#?

Comment: I don't really know a lot about the internals, but it looks like the F# source code defining the `+` operator (C:\Program Files (x86)\FSharp-2.0.0.0\source\fsharp\FSharp.Core\prim-types.fs line 3527) switches on the argument types at compile type and emits IL code directly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As suggested by `inline`, the code is inlined at the call site.  At every call site, you know the concrete type parameter `^T`, so the specific code for that type is inserted there.

This is done by the F# compiler, you can't easily do it in other context (like C# or Ref.Emit).

The F# library has some inline functions that can still be called by other languages, the runtime for those implementations does dynamic dispatch based on the runtime type, see e.g. the code for `AdditionDynamic` in `prim-types.fs` in the F# Core library code to get a feel.

Comment: So you're saying its basically an elaborate compiler trick? If I call an `FSharpFunc<,>` from C# would I get the desired behavior?

Comment: Any instance of the type `FSharpFunc` (or indeed most types) is not (and cannot) be `inline`.  `inline` applies to methods and functions, and only a handful of them in the F# library.  Most stuff can be called fine from C#, but a few F# `inline` functions that do not support dynamic invocation (like `sin`) can only be called from F#, since the F# compiler must inline the code at the call site.