# Operator (-) used in F# raises Specified method is not supported exception from C#

Tags: c#, f#, mono, c#-to-f#

I have this generic function in F# that uses (-) operator:

`let inline sub a b = a - b`

Now I'm calling this function from C#:

`int a = sub<int, int, int>(4, 1);`

This raises an error:

> Unhandled Exception: System.NotSupportedException: Specified method is
>   not supported.   at ProjA.MainClass.Main (System.String[] args)
>   [0x00000] in <4f209fa43741462db3b8f73ac83c35a2>:0 [ERROR] FATAL
>   UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.NotSupportedException: Specified method is
>   not supported.   at ProjA.MainClass.Main (System.String[] args)
>   [0x00000] in <4f209fa43741462db3b8f73ac83c35a2>:0

Please note that this works fine for (+) operator or without the inline keyword.

1) Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

2) Is there any way to overcome this issue (but I need the inline keyword to make this function generic)?

3) Have you experienced something similar when calling f# function from c#, how did you solve it?

I'm using Mono 4.8 on macOS Sierra.

Comment: @EJoshuaS Compiler itself enforces three parameters, the last one for return type. Type arguments cannot be inferred automatically by the compiler. As I mentioned, the weird thing is that when I change (-) to (+) everything works fine without an exception.

Comment: Yes, please ignore my previous comment, I saw that once I tried it myself. I'm a little surprised by that kind of behavior too (I saw the exact same thing on my machine). Apparently the "inline" keyword [can be a little weird](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4413324/how-does-f-inline-work) when calling from C# to F# - in fact, when I remove the inline function it behaves correctly - but I'm a little baffled as to why this would work for "+" but not "-". I'd actually really like to see an explanation for why this is too if someone knows.

Comment: I would be surprised that this even works - I suspect that you are probably shadowing the definition of something else if you use +.  For inline, the F# compiler doesn't actually create a function, it just creates some metadata that it can use.  The fact that the C# compiler sees it at all is thus surprising

Comment: Is this error mode specific to Mono, or can it be reproduced with `NotSupportedException` in Microsoft implementation as well?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, functions declared as `inline` will not be usable (or will not work the same as from F#) from other languages.  They are replaced at the call site as a feature of the F# compiler, which is not supported by C# and other CLR languages.  This is a significant advantage of F# over these other languages.

However, there are some exceptions.  It is possible to write F# inline functions which perform dispatch based on the runtime type, which is then usable from C# and other languages.  Typically, these will not get the same IL when used from C# as they do from F# for certain types (the specific handlers for primitive types will not be handled).  This is why `(+)` works - you can see [this in the code for the operator](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/prim-types.fs#L3929), where `(+)` calls `AdditionDynamic<(^T),(^U),(^V)>  x y`.  Note that `(-)` [is missing the runtime dispatched version](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/prim-types.fs#L3951), and is explicitly marked as `[<NoDynamicInvocation>]`, which is why it fails to work from C#.

This is effectively the same limitation in C# that has caused people to request things like [IArithmetic](https://web.archive.org/web/20100614053012/http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/94264/arithmetic-types-like-int-double-decimal-should-implement-iarithmetic-t) (*using Internet Archive since it's been hidden in Connect) for many years.  F# works around this via [statically resolved type parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/generics/statically-resolved-type-parameters), but this is a *feature specific to F#*, and will not work from C# and other languages.  Wrapping the function through F# doesn't enable it in C#.